# How can I edit the content of my smart card?

Tags: smartcard, apdu, mifare

Can you tell me please how I can edit the content of my smart card?
How should I use APDU commands in order to edit the content?

Lets say I have something like this on a smart card:

```
00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And I want it to be :

```
00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

How can I do that? Is it possible? If yes, how?

I have `ACR-122 NFC READER/writer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about simple Mifare tags apparently?

ACR122 has its own [API manual](http://www.acr122.com/NFC-smart-card-reader/ACR122-API-Manual/API_ACR122.pdf) for wrapping the RFID in the CCID frames to talk to tags, first have a look at this.

It also contains practical examples with mifare data tags.